# Mongod Process starts but Systemctl status shows failed

Tags: mongodb, redhat

I have created a mongod configuration in `/home/cluster1.conf` with the same port I used previously for `etc/mongod.conf`.

I used to run `etc/mongod.conf` as a sudo user but expect to run `cluster1.conf` as user.

when I run `cluster1.conf` as user, the process starts. I accessed it from mongo shell and did operations. But when I'm trying to access it from another vm from the same VPC, it failed.

I checked for `systemctl status mongod` and it shows service is not running.

Why does `systemctl status` shows it not running when it really does? How can I resolve this to create a replica set??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*when I run `cluster1.conf` as user, the process starts.*" does not make much sense. `cluster1.conf` is a configuration file, it does not start anything.

When you run `systemctl status mongod`, then it typically shows

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-08-27 09:44:26 CEST; 2 weeks 3 days ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
 Main PID: 38710 (mongod)
    Tasks: 28
   Memory: 270.8M
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
           └─38710 /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
```

Check the service file `/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service` there you see entry like

```
Environment="OPTIONS=-f /etc/mongod.conf"
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/mongod
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS
```

Which means, config file `/etc/mongod.conf` is used (rather than `/home/cluster1.conf`)